# How to find ids with sum of multiple rows in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, logic, data-analysis

Here is my mysql table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  tbl_money  (
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   amount  int(11) NOT NULL,
   used  int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO  tbl_money  ( id ,  amount ,  used ) VALUES
(8, 2, 0),
(9, 4, 0),
(10, 4, 0),
(11, 3, 0),
(12, 8, 0),
(13, 10, 0),
(14, 13, 0);
```

Id is a primary key field and money can have any number from 1 to any number.

Problem:
Suppose i have to find id from the table where amount is 8. It is simple because id 5 contains amount 8. But if i have to find id with 14 amount which does not exist. I have to select 2 or more fields now which sum will be equal to 14. For example in above table i can select id 6 and id 3 which amount sum is equal to 14. Same as if i need to find 6 i have to select id 1 and 2 because their amount sum is equal to six.

Sometime there we may need to select more than 2 rows to make equal sum. But if any condition does't match with all rows of the table, we can return 0.

Condition: 
The row which is already taken that cannot be selected again. Used field should always be 0. If used fields value is 1 we cannot select it. We will only search for even number so we don't need to worry with odd numbers.

Please suggest me how to solve this algorithm. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your table structure is wrong. id int(11) NOT NULL, should be id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY

Comment: If that is the case, then to get value `4`, `id 1,2 and 5` can also be chosen. Because you have mentioned `two or more fields`.

Comment: @Viki888 yes bro. That is also option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure SQL way to do it, which probably isn't that efficient:-

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', a.id, b.id, c.id, d.id)
FROM tbl_money a
INNER JOIN tbl_money b ON b.id > a.id
INNER JOIN tbl_money c ON c.id > b.id
INNER JOIN tbl_money d ON d.id > c.id
WHERE a.amount + b.amount + c.amount + d.amount = 14
UNION
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', a.id, b.id, c.id)
FROM tbl_money a
INNER JOIN tbl_money b ON b.id > a.id
INNER JOIN tbl_money c ON c.id > b.id
WHERE a.amount + b.amount + c.amount = 14
UNION
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', a.id, b.id)
FROM tbl_money a
INNER JOIN tbl_money b ON b.id > a.id
WHERE a.amount + b.amount = 14
UNION
SELECT a.id
FROM tbl_money a
WHERE a.amount = 14
```

EDIT - modified to check the used field, and also that the amounts are not odd numbers

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', a.id, b.id, c.id, d.id)
FROM tbl_money a
INNER JOIN tbl_money b ON b.id > a.id AND b.used = 1 AND MOD(b.amount, 2) = 0
INNER JOIN tbl_money c ON c.id > b.id AND c.used = 1 AND MOD(c.amount, 2) = 0
INNER JOIN tbl_money d ON d.id > c.id AND d.used = 1 AND MOD(d.amount, 2) = 0
WHERE a.amount + b.amount + c.amount + d.amount = 14
AND a.used = 1
AND MOD(a.amount, 2) = 0
UNION
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', a.id, b.id, c.id)
FROM tbl_money a
INNER JOIN tbl_money b ON b.id > a.id AND b.used = 1 AND MOD(b.amount, 2) = 0
INNER JOIN tbl_money c ON c.id > b.id AND c.used = 1 AND MOD(c.amount, 2) = 0
WHERE a.amount + b.amount + c.amount = 14
AND a.used = 1
AND MOD(a.amount, 2) = 0
UNION
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', a.id, b.id)
FROM tbl_money a
INNER JOIN tbl_money b ON b.id > a.id AND b.used = 1 AND MOD(b.amount, 2) = 0
WHERE a.amount + b.amount = 14
AND a.used = 1
AND MOD(a.amount, 2) = 0
UNION
SELECT a.id
FROM tbl_money a
WHERE a.amount = 14
AND a.used = 1
AND MOD(a.amount, 2) = 0
```

Comment: You are Genious

Comment: can you check my updated question please. Your answer worked perfectly but i got one more conditon of `used` column. Thanks

Comment: @KrishnaKarki - mod added

Comment: Thank you @kickstart. You are really a great programmer. How did you learn queries like this?

Comment: @KrishnaKarki - thank you. You learn from trying things out (and failing quite often). Questions on here are a good way to get you thinking about how to do things.

Answer (score 1):

Below is just an idea, try implementing it in function or SP.

**Idea 1:**

i. Find whether the value which you got is **ODD** or **EVEN**.

ii. If even, then try adding **two EVEN** numbers or **two ODD** numbers in your
        table and check whether it matches your value.

iii. If odd, then try adding **One EVEN** number and **One ODD** number from your table and check whether it matches your value.

iv. If you did not get the result, then

- if even, add **three EVEN** numbers
- if odd, add **three ODD** numbers or **TWO EVEN** numbers and **ONE ODD** number

**Idea 2:** (This would be quite simple)

i. Take **first** value say from your sample data, take value `2` and add with other row values like `2+4 == 14, 2+4 == 14, 2+3 == 14, 2+8 == 14, 2+10 == 14, 2+13 == 14`

ii. Then take **2nd row value** say value `4` and add with other values like `4+4 == 14, 4+3 == 14, 4+8 == 14, 4+10== 14, 4+13 == 14`. Here `4+10` matches the value `14`. (If you need all the combination then proceed else break with this execution).

iii. Once till `10+13` combination is done, then add first two values and add with other values such as `6+4, 6+3, 6+8, 6+10, 6+13`

iv. proceed until the combination `31(2+4+4+3+8+10)+13`

Hope this would help you a bit.